# JUnit - assertSame

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

Can someone tell me why assertSame() do fail when I use values > 127?

```
        import static org.junit.Assert.*;

        ...

        @Test
        public void StationTest1() {
          ..

          assertSame(4, 4);         // OK
          assertSame(10, 10);       // OK
          assertSame(100, 100);     // OK
          assertSame(127, 127);     // OK
          assertSame(128, 128);           // raises an junit.framework.AssertionFailedError!
          assertSame(((int) 128),((int) 128)); // also junit.framework.AssertionFailedError!
        }
```

I'm using JUnit 4.8.1.

Comment: You should use `assertSame` only for reference equality checks - for example `a == b`. For equality, you should use `assertEquals`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The reason is the autoboxing of Java. 
You use the method:

```
public static void assertSame(Object expected, Object actual)
```

It only works with Objects. When you pass `int`s to this method, Java automatically calls

```
Integer.valueOf( int i )
```

with these values. So the cast to `int` has no effect.

For values less than 128 Java has a cache, so `assertSame()` compares the `Integer` object with itself. For values greater than 127 Java creates new instances, so `assertSame()` compares an `Integer` object with another. Because they are not the same instance, the `assertSame()` method returns false.

You should use the method:

```
public static void assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual)
```

instead. This method uses the `equals()` method from `Object`.

Comment: You are correct that the JVM *must* cache -128..127, but for values outside that range, that is entirely up to the JVM implementation what range it caches,  
_"Less memory-limited implementations might, for example, cache all char and short values, as well as int and long values in the range of -32K to +32K."_ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7 via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127/20948389#20948389

Answer (score 12):

`assertSame` takes two `Object` arguments, and so the compiler has to autobox your `int` literals into `Integer`.

This is equivalent to

```
assertSame(Integer.valueOf(128), Integer.valueOf(128));
```

Now for values between -128 and 127, the JVM will cache the results of `Integer.valueOf`, so you get the same `Integer` object back each time. For values outside of that range, you get new objects back.

So for `assertSame(127, 127)`, JUnit is comparing the same objects, hence it works. For `assertSame(128, 128)`, you get different objects, so it fails.

Just another reason to be careful with autoboxing.

Comment: You are correct that the JVM must cache -128..127, but for values outside that range, that is entirely up to the JVM implementation what range it caches, _"Less memory-limited implementations might, for example, cache all char and short values, as well as int and long values in the range of -32K to +32K."_ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7 via https://stackoverflow.com/a/20948389/360211