# why integer wrapper cases instances in range of -128 to 127

Tags: java, wrapper

Here they are the same instance:

```
Integer integer1 = 127;
Integer integer2 = 127;
System.out.println(integer1 == integer2);  // outputs "true"
```

But here they are different instances:

```
Integer integer1 = 128;
Integer integer2 = 128;
System.out.println(integer1 == integer2);  // outputs "false"
```

Why do the wrapper class case the objects in this range?
I have read the [JLS 5.1.7 Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7). My question is why architect decided to do maintain case for this range ?

Comment: is it like many algorithms use small integers in their calculations, so avoiding the object-creation overhead for these values tends to be worthwhile?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20948389/1897572

> Just wondering, why between -128 and 127?
>
> A larger range of integers may be cached, but at least those between
>   -128 and 127 must be cached because it is mandated by the Java Language Specification (emphasis mine):
>
> ```
> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and
> ```
>
> 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.
>
> The rationale for this requirement is explained in the same paragraph:
>
> ```
> Ideally, boxing a given primitive value p, would always yield an identical reference. In practice, this may not be feasible using
> ```
>
> existing implementation techniques. The rules above are a pragmatic
>   compromise. The final clause above requires that certain common values
>   always be boxed into indistinguishable objects. [...]
>
> ```
> This ensures that in most common cases, the behavior will be the desired one, without imposing an undue performance penalty, especially
> ```
>
> on small devices. Less memory-limited implementations might, for
>   example, cache all char and short values, as well as int and long
>   values in the range of -32K to +32K.
>
> How can I cache other values outside of this range.?
>
> You can use the -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax JVM option, which is not really
>   documented in the list of available Hotspot JVM Options. However it is
>   mentioned in the comments inside the Integer class around line 590:
>
> ```
> The size of the cache may be controlled by the -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size> option.
> ```
>
> Note that this is implementation specific and may or may not be
>   available on other JVMs.

Comment: is it like many algorithms use small integers in their calculations, so avoiding the object-creation overhead for these values tends to be worthwhile?

Comment: I thanks for your help.. but, really I can't get this.. please elaborate me in Lehman Language

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this and found from other source and @nos, that it is like many algorithms use small integers in their calculations, so avoiding the object-creation overhead for these values tends to be worthwhile.

PS : if any one wants to add more reason behind this casing idea, You can edit my answer. this will later help people like me.