# Using Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem using Arraylists in java my code looks something like this:

```
List<Integer> numbers1 =  new ArrayList<>(); 
List<Integer> numbers2 =  new ArrayList<>();
boolean bcompare;
```

I add to the lists the same numbers, but when i try to compare the numbers of the index 0 of the lists like this the result of the boolean is false when it should be true:

```
bcompare = numbers1.get(0)==numbers2.get(0);
```

`bcompare` is false

But here is the thing when I use some temp variables and then compare them it gives me what i expected, a true value on bcompare:

```
int a=numbers1.get(0);
int b=numbers2.get(0);
bcompare = a==b;
```

`bcompare` is true

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does your `ArrayList` contain any elements? Which ones?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 3):

It is cause you use the wrapper classes Integer. So an `==` compares the "references".
Use the `equals()` method instead to compare values of objects:

```
bcompare = numbers1.get(0).equals(numbers2.get(0));
```

The second comparison is true, because a `int` is a primitive type and contains only the value.

Have a look at http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html for more details about the difference between `int` and `Integer`

Answer (score 2):

When compare the results of `get`, you are comparing `Integer`s.  Using `==`, this will compare the two object references to see if they are the same reference.  With the exception of [`Integer` caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127), this will be `false`.

When you first assign the numbers to `int`, Java unboxes the `Integer` to `int`, so that `==` can compare the primitive values directly.  This works as you intended.

Use the last code which uses `int` values.

Comment: I ran his code by inserting 1 in both `numbers1` and `numbers2` and it returns `true`. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is the code: `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();list.add(1);
  list2.add(1);
  boolean bcompare = list.get(0)==list2.get(0);
  System.out.println(bcompare);`

Comment: @ArchitVerma I indicated with the link to the SO question about `Integer` question.  The values at least in the range `-128` to `127` are cached, so that the `Integer`s for `1` in both lists are actually the same.

Answer (score 0):

return type of get() method is Object so when you are comparing like this

```
bcompare = numbers1.get(0).equals(numbers2.get(0));
```

It compares the reference of two different object so giving false.

either use equals() method or downcast it to the Integer class.

Using equals() method is good idea out of these both.

Answer (score 0):

As,others have already said `bcompare = numbers1.get(0)==numbers2.get(0);` compares references of 2 Integer objects (which are not same, so, it will be false). `int a=numbers1.get(0);` extracts the *int value* from Integers ( by calling `integer.intValue()` *implicitly*) and compares them so, `a==b;` will be true.

Byte code :

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
   *** some code here***
        30: if_acmpne     37   // byte code instruction to compare references
        49: invokevirtual #27                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
    *** some other code here **
```