# Override method "equals" doesn't work over 99 id

Tags: java, overriding

I found this code to use ArrayList.contains with java object:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object)
{
    boolean equals = false;

    if (object != null && object instanceof User)
    {
        equals= this.getId() == ((User) object).getId();
    }

    return equals;
}
```

Until objects with id 99, this method work fine, but over 99 it returns ever false, can someone help me?

```
if(users.contains(user)){return true;}
```

Comment: What type does getId() return?

Comment: What does your `hashCode()` look like?

Comment: id is a Long type, I didn't override the hashCode method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Integer class caching values in the range -128 to 127?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127)

Comment: Not sure why it is working to 99, it should work to 127, and it is related to integer caching

Comment: Can you show a runnable example (including the failing call to `ArrayList.contains`) that reproduces the problem? Your equals implementation doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Comment: Rather use `this.getId().equals(((User) object).getId())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java uses caching of numbers for non-primitive types. So until some value (127 for Integer) you'll have same object for numbers.

Change your '==' to equals() to make it work.