# Strange Logical Error in Java Code

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

```
interface New<T> {
   boolean func(T n, T v);
}
```

```
class MyFunc<T>{
T val;
MyFunc(T val){
   this.val = val;
}
void Set(T val){
   this.val = val;
}
T Get(){
   return val;
}
boolean isEqual(MyFunc<T> o){
   if(val == o.val) return true;
return false;
}
```

```
public class Main {
  static <T> boolean check(New<T> n , T a, T b){
     return n.func(a,b);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
   int a = 321;
   MyFunc<Integer> f1 = new MyFunc<Integer>(a);
   MyFunc<Integer> f2 = new MyFunc<Integer>(a);

   boolean result;
   //f2.Set(f1.Get()); //if i uncomment this line result become true
   System.out.println(f1.val + "  " + f2.val);
   System.out.println();

   result = check(MyFunc::isEqual, f1, f2);
   System.out.println("f1 isEqual to f2: " + result);
  }
}
```

Why result is false when `'a'` is used in both `f1` and `f2`?
Why result is true when `f2.Set(f1.Get());` is uncommented?
Please explain me where I am making mistake.

Comment: It is not making any sense why result is **false** when i used `a` in both `f1` and `f2`. and it become **true** when i use `f2.Set(f1.Get());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `.isEquals()` method you're comparing tho wrapper objects with the `==` operator, which compares the objects references if those are not within the `Integer` internal cache.

Since `321` is out of the `Integer` cache, the `==` operator returns `false`, because the references are different (`f1` refers to different memory address than `f2`).

When you **explicitly** set the references to be equal (with `f2.Set(f1.Get())`), then it's not surprising the program outputs `true`.

If you set `a` to something between `-128` and `127`, the program will output `true`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Can you tell me how `321` is out of the `Integer` cache and why output become true if value of `a` is set less then 128

Comment: Read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127)

Answer (score 3):

`a` is [auto boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to `Integer` and for `int a = 321;` you will have two different `Objects` for `f1` and `f2`.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
Integer a1 = new Integer(321);
Integer a2 = new Integer(321);
```

and for `a1 == a2` you will have `false` because `==` compare reference instead of value you should use `equals` method to check value in your `isEqual` method.