# Compare two elements in an ArrayList using == operator

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, compare, comparison

I want to compare two elements in an ArrayList `== operator`, I write this code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArray=new ArrayList<>();
myArray.add(-128);
myArray.add(-128);
System.out.println(myArray.get(0)==myArray.get(1));
```

I get `true` as result, but with other value like:

```
myArray.add(2000);
myArray.add(2000);
System.out.println(myArray.get(0)==myArray.get(1));
```

I get `false` as result.

I know that `== operator` **Compares references, not values**, in this case the two Integers have different references, so logically we must have `false` for both case.
I don't understand Why I get `true` for only an `Integer` from `-128 to 127` and `false` for other `Integer`.

**NB: I see many questions in Stackoverflow and Google, but I can't find an answer of my question**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127

Comment: Ok I see that: For values between the range of -128 to 127 Java points all the Integer/ int references to the same object to save memory. for more details http://bexhuff.com/2006/11/java-1-5-autoboxing-wackyness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in range `-128 -> 127` are cached in `Integer` class.

Comment: Do we really need more duplicates? Please just vote to close.