# Number.valueOf() implementation for Java generics

Tags: java, generics, casting, numbers

I have been using a `Collection` of number values and have implemented some related functionality (mapping x->y values, etc). So far I have made use of generics to allow any subclass of `Number` in the `Collection`.

In this particular class I keep running into the problem that there is no easy way to cast to the generic. The usual methods like `Double.valueOf()` cannot be invoked because `Number` does not provide such a method.

Is there a good way around this?

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368235/java-get-valueof-for-generic-subclass-of-java-lang-number-or-primitive) and thought that would solve it, but I cannot pass the `Class.class` parameter to it.

```
public class myList<T extends Number> extends Collection<T> {

  @Override
  public boolean add(T value){
    // this is no problem
  }

  // What I want to do:
  public boolean add(double value){
    return this.add(T.valueOf(value)); 
  }

  // Using the example I found:
  public void add(double value){
    return this.add( (T) Ideone.parse(value, T.class) ); // no such option
  }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way for the `myList` class to be able to convert `double` to `T`, because `T` is unknown.

One way you can solve this is to let the caller provide a function that converts from `double` to `T`. Here's an example:

```
public class myList<T extends Number> implements Collection<T> {

    private DoubleFunction<T> fromDoubleFunction;

    public myList(DoubleFunction<T> function) {
        this.fromDoubleFunction = function;
    }

    public boolean add(double value) {
        return this.add(this.fromDoubleFunction.apply(value));
    }

    //rest of code
}
```

That can then be used in this way:

```
myList<Integer> intList = new myList(d -> Double.valueOf(d).intValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide a [`DoubleFunction<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleFunction.html) to your class as a constructor parameter.

```
public class myList<T extends Number> extends Collection<T> { 
  private final DoubleFunction<T> theDoubleFn;

  public myList(DoubleFunction<T> theDoubleFn) {
    this.theDoubleFn = theDoubleFn;
  }

  // ...
```

Then invoke:

```
return this.add(theDoubleFn.apply(value));
```

in the method.

Comment: Unrelated: if you have a minute or two, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55650516/1531124 and let me know what you think about the two answers given on that question.