# Why is the output of following code different in the two print statements?

Tags: java

Following is what I have written. Line 5 and line and line 8 should be same as

> true

but they are different. I am not able to figure out what is actually happening. Help

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer i1 = 127;

        Integer i2 = 127;

        System.out.println(i1 == i2);  //Shows true 

        Integer i3 = 128;

        Integer i4 = 128;

        System.out.println(i3 == i4);  // shows false
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20948389/1369579 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/3130348/1369579

Comment: Good spot and good question, despite being a duplicate. One of the most pernicious parts of Java, in my opinion. The duplicates explain the reasons.

Comment: `i3 == i4` compares the _objects_, not the _values_.  Use `i3.intValue() == i4.intValue()` if you want to compare the values.

Comment: Or you can ace it with `i3.intValue() == i4`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Also `(int) i3 == i4`

Comment: Note that `i3 == i4` *can* be true. The documentation requires `Integer.valueOf` to cache the results for -128..127, but does not forbid caching other values. It depends upon the implementation you are using.

Comment: See also this http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5/28818#28818 where you can manipulate the cache to make the comparisons say anything you want. And they claim Java is a "secure" language.