# Java reflection update number

Tags: java, reflection

I am new to Java reflection. I am trying to make a program where addition of two numbers gives custom result. Below is the code:

```
public class MoreTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Field field = Integer.class.getDeclaredField( "value" );
            field.setAccessible( true );
            field.setInt(Integer.valueOf(2),2);             

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( 2 + 4 ); // should print 8
    }

}
```

What I can do in the above code to print the output I need?

Comment: Are you trying to make an [integer bomb](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/Disgruntled-Bomb-Java-Edition)?

Comment: Why you expect it should print 8

Comment: @RC., Yes, I was trying for the same as I read there and was just playing with the reflection to know its power.

Comment: So your issue is as stated in bowmore answer the "set" on the field, it's `setInt(target object, new value)` and off course you have to use the `Integer` object (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127 for the why this is possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you just rewrite 2 to... 2 instead of 4...

try replacing this :

```
field.setInt(Integer.valueOf(2), 2);
```

by this

```
field.setInt(Integer.valueOf(2), 4);
```

in your code

Then :

```
Integer a = 2;
System.out.println( a + 4 ); // will print 8
```

This works because `Integer a = 2;` triggers autoboxing, the compiler replaces this with `Integer a = Integer.valueOf(2);`, which is the instance from the cache you doctored earlier to have value 4.

In the expression `a + 4` auto-unboxing is used; the compiler replaces that with `a.intValue() + 4`.

In the expression `2 + 4` (using numeric `int` literals) the values are both primitives, and no `Integer`class instances are used.

Comment: It is not printing like this, but when I make it to `System.out.println( (Integer)2+(Integer)2 );`, it works. Can you explain me how it works as per your solution if suppose I need to print `2+2` should be `5`. Thanks

Comment: you can't make `2+2` print 5. these numeric numerals are backed by the primitive `int` type, not the `Integer` class