# Kotlin reference equality for "Byte" numbers

Tags: kotlin, equality

In official Kotlin reference https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#numbers I read that:

> Note that boxing of numbers does not necessarily preserve identity

and example which shows how it can be represented:

```
val a: Int = 10000
print(a === a) // Prints 'true'
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
print(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // !!!Prints 'false'!!!
```

After some spontaneous testing I realized that it works as should for byte numbers  (<128):

```
val a = 127
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
print(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) //!!!Prints 'true'!!!
```

Also in the same reference https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html  I have found that:

> For values which are represented as primitive types at runtime (for example, Int), the === equality check is equivalent to the == check

But this doesn't explain this case as for:

```
val a = 128
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
print(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) //!!!Prints 'false'!!!
```

So I am trying to get a glue why referential equality "===" shows "false" for numbers >=128 and "true" for <128?

Comment: Due to caching in the JDK. Check out the source code of `Byte.valueOf()`, which is used for boxing. However, when you say it "doesn't work", that isn't true. "It" works every time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks will check it and yeah it works always, I rephrased explanation a bit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes from how [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) is implemented for the *JVM*:

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

So for `a = 127` the identity `box1 === box2` always holds true, while for all non `byte` values it might not.