# Which is the difference between Long.valueOf(0) and 0L in Java?

Tags: java, types

I would like to know the difference between using `Long.valueOf(0);` or `0L`. Are they the same?

I understand that both are [Long types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) so they have a memory consumption of 64-bits long in Java 8.

So how it is better to initialize a variable, considering memory consumption and time complexity?

`Long a = Long.valueOf(0);`

or

`Long b = 0L;`

Comment: "I understand that both are Long types" - `Long#valueOf` returns an object of type `Long`, and `0L` is a primitive `long`.

Comment: `Long::value` will give you an `Object`, `0L` a primitive (that you can box via `Long b = OL;` - that internally will still use `Long::valueOf`)

Comment: Side note: in the range [-128,127] `Long.valueOf(x)` will return the same instance while every other primitive will cause a new instance to be created, i.e. you'll get a `new Long(x)` every time.

Comment: @Thomas, That's interesting.... Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @lealceldeiro the JavaDoc and the source of `valueOf()` for `Long`, `Integer`, `Short`, `Byte` and `Character` tell you. :)  Some more information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127

Comment: What is not covered in your question, the difference from `Long` <-> `long`. Could you edit your question to include this? Like : `Long a = Long.valueOf(0);Long b = OL; long c = 0L;`

Comment: It is a mistake to use `Long` in cases where `long` will do. The memory usage of `Long` is several times that of `long`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nothing.

```
Long b = 0L;
```

will undergo [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). The compiler replaces it with:

```
Long b = Long.valueOf(0L);
```

You can see this if you decompile your class, e.g. using `javap`.

```
void a() {
  Long a = Long.valueOf(0);
}

void b() {
  Long b = 0L;
}
```

Decompiles to:

```
  void a();
    Code:
       0: lconst_0
       1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
       4: astore_1
       5: return

  void b();
    Code:
       0: lconst_0
       1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
       4: astore_1
       5: return
```

> So how it is better initialize a variable, considering memory consumption and time complexity?

Because they are semantically identical, the memory consumption and time complexity is also identical.

Instead, focus on what is actually important, which is *readability*: use the one you (and others) will find most easy to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, `Long l = Long.valueOf(0)` and `Long l = 0L` will compile to the same bytecode, the only difference is style and readability.

Additionally..

It's a bit silly to worry about time complexity for something like this: both expressions are constant time. You *usually* only talk about time complexity when acting on collections of data not just a single piece of data.

As for memory consumption, they do not use 64 bits as you say; It's the primitive `long` type that typically uses 64 bits but `Long` (the wrapper type) uses more memory than the primitive type because it needs that memory for object-related stuff.