# Assert statement Assert.assertSame is failing

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, assert

I have the following code in a `junit` test case. The first Assert passes and the second one fails.

```
final int code = webResponse.getResponseCode();
Assert.assertTrue(200 == code);  //passes
Assert.assertSame(200, code);    //fails
```

Why does the second one fail?  webResponse is type [WebResponse](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/WebResponse.html) and all implementations of getResponseCode return an int.

I am running the code within a junit test and the second assert fails in both Intellij and Eclipse IDE. Also, in Intellij, it provides a link to "Click to see difference" but when I click that, it says "Contents are identical".

Comment: I think it's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882337/junit-assertsame

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`assertSame(Object, Object)` checks if both arguments refer to the same object.

It performs boxing conversion to convert `200` to a valid reference type object. To do this, it does

```
Integer.valueOf(200);
```

and

```
Integer.valueOf(code);
```

which return new object references which do not reference the same object.

Comment: More about it is here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882337/junit-assertsame

Comment: Oh ok good to know, I had thought to use assertSame when I wanted to use `==` and assertEquals when I wanted to use `.equals`. But I see now that I should use assertSame only when comparing two references.

Comment: @jlars62 `assertSame()` here would actually worked if code had been between -128 and 127 due to `Integer` caching.